# A null exception occurs when generating a Linq expression that Process.GetProcesses.Where method

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

There is a process to get the running process from the string.

```
Dim processName As String = "foo"

Dim qProcess As IEnumerable(Of Process) = Process.GetProcesses.Where(Function(x) x.ProcessName.ToUpper = processName.ToUpper())

Return qProcess.FirstOrDefault() IsNot Nothing
```

In rare cases, a null reference exception occurs in the Where method.

Stack trace at that:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at NameSpace.MyClass._Closure$__1-0._Lambda$__0(Process x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at NameSpace.MyClass.MyMethod()
```

I experienced for the first time that qProcess became Nothing.
When does this exception?
It seems to happen just after rebooting the machine.

p.s.
How do you name variable names in linq expressions?
I prefix "q" (eg qProcess)

thanks.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: You appear to be trying to perform a case-insensitive comparison and you're going about it the wrong way.  If you do it the right way then it wouldn't matter if one of the `Strings` is `Nothing`.  `Function(x) String.Equals(x.ProcessName, processName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: `Return Process.GetProcesses.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.ProcessName.Equals(processName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) IsNot Nothing`

Comment: @Jimi, that would still throw a `NullReferenceException` if `ProcessName` is `Nothing`.  You need to call a `Shared` overload of `String.Equals` to avoid calling an instance method on a nonexistent instance.  You could switch the property and the local variable around though: `processName.Equals(p.ProcessName`.

Comment: @Jimi, I agree that calling `FirstOrDefault` and passing a predicate is better than calling `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` but, based on the code in the question, there's still a better way.  If you don't actually need the matching object(s) then just call `Any`: `Return Process.GetProcesses().Any(Function(p) String.Equals(p.ProcessName, processName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `ProcessName` cannot be null (it's the name of the executable or the name of the runner - rundll, dllhost, conhost etc.- or it's a system name). Here, `qProcess` can be `null`; in this case, `FirstOrDefault` is used on a `null` object, hence the exception (a note for the OP). I agree that if you just want to return a bool, `Any` is probably more *naturally equipped* for this and `IsNot Nothing` is ugly). `FirstOrDefault` can be used to return the actual Process (or `null`), if needed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What is not handled in any case is the `InvalidOperationException`, if the Process (or its identifier) becomes invalid while enumerating and the common Processes bitness mishap. These two may deserve a note.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the second comment in the question.